# How to provide alias for the property that is extracted as a column using inline function on Azure Databricks

Tags: sql, json, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a metadata field saved as JSON and has the structure as shown below

```json
{"IDH": [{"ID": "ABCD", "name": "1111"},
         {"id": "EFGH", "name": "2222"}], 
 "RSN": "1000"}
```

Wrote the below SQL and I m able to extract the data

```sql
SELECT inv.InventoryId, inv.Metadata, inv.Metadata:RSN as `RSN`,  
  INLINE
  (
    FROM_JSON( UPPER(inv.Metadata:IDH[*]), 'array<struct<ID:string,NAME:string>>')
  )
  FROM inventory inv
```

There are essentially two problems:

1. Casing of attribute field (id) is not consistent inside JSON
2. I would like to change the way I extract the column encased inside json... for instance get ID and as 'IDH_ID' and name AS 'IDH_Name' when I execute the SQL.

For first problem.. I upper cased the text which works for the time being... However I do not want to alter the casing of values. Is there a way to ignore casing of the attribute/ map the attribute name?

For second problem I was able to use CTEs .. but noticed that the queries took lot more time to execute.
Is it possible to specifies alias within the query and address the above two problems?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the data i re-created in my environment.

[image]

You can use below query.
Using `maptype` i am getting records and again creating
`array<struct<>>` for doing `inline`.

```
SELECT
inv.InventoryId, inv.Metadata, inv.Metadata:RSN as RSN,
explode(FROM_JSON(inv.Metadata:IDH, 'ARRAY<MAP<string,string>>')) as tmp,
inline(array(named_struct('gid',map_values(tmp)[0],'gname',map_values(tmp)[1])))
FROM inventory inv
```

I have indexed with 0 and 1 on map type if you have more column you can try creating struct like below

```
SELECT  struct(c1,  c2,  c3)  FROM  VALUES(1,  2,  3)  AS  T(c1,  c2,  c3);
```

Out:
`{"c1":1,"c2":2,"c3":3}`

And use it in above query instead of `named_struct`.

Output:

[image]

Here you can see whatever the column name , upper or lower it is creating id and name column successfully.